# Filling duplicates consecutivly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets that talk together in google sheets. whatever I put in sheet 1 it will show on sheet 2. The problem is I have duplicate values in sheet 2. For example: In sheet 2, The first column has these values: B1, B2, B1, B7. When I insert the value in sheet 1: B1 = 5, B2= 2, B1= 6, B7 = 8. The output that I am getting in sheet 2 is B1=5, B2 = 2, B1= 5, B7= 8. How can I make it fill B1 = 5 and then the second  B1 =  6?

[image]

This is how I built it:

```
=VLOOKUP(B3, IMPORTRANGE("1XTOfpirZufwJKyiZuSN7QP-OKtgq8tREbe3nUJqhXwU","'1814'!B2:c11"),2,0)
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide better visuals for Sheet1 and Sheet2? You can insert clipped screenshots (for focus). Show us what your expected result should be. For me, it's a bit difficult to follow in your question currently.

Comment: Just added it, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the images. The issue is that you are getting two `DT32-208, 11` and two `DT32-133, 16` when it should be 15 and 17 respectively, right? What are you trying to accomplish by copying Sheet 1 to Sheet 2?

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 2):

I understand what's going on. Don't use [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) for this, because it returns the first result where there is a match. So if you have duplicates, `VLOOKUP` will still return the first result.

Just set up your sheet with only the `IMPORTRANGE("sheet_key","'1814'!B2:c11")`. You'll bring in a copy of that sheet, and you can perform subsequent calculations after that.

If you have additional criteria to filter, let us know.

Comment: I think that I have to use Vlookup to find the duplicates. The two sheets are not in order. I put them in order for this example so it will be easier to explain.

Comment: @Luke Are you needing to just sort the data? Your expectations aren't clear.

Comment: I need to insert information in sheet one, then this information will go to sheet 2 and look for the same value and put it there. The problem I am having is when there is duplicates. It does what in the pictures that I submitted!

Comment: @Luke, You still haven't explained what your end goal is. Currently it sounds like you want two copies of the same data in different sheets.

Comment: Yes that is what I need!

Comment: @Luke, Then remove the `VLOOKUP` formula altogether. The [`ImportRange`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) function handles what you need by itself.

Comment: Vlookup is to find the similar pieces.

Comment: @Luke Could you update your question with the final result you wish to achieve? Perhaps with more sample data. Can you be more specific about "similar pieces"?